# Product not being calculated correctly (PHP)

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors','1'); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once 'dbConnect.php';

    if (connect()){
        global $conn;

        $queryProduct = "SELECT group_concat(candName) FROM testFacRep";    

        $productResult = $conn->query($queryProduct);
        $productResult = mysqli_fetch_row($productResult);
        $data = $productResult[0];

        $cipher = explode(",", $data);

        function product($carry, $item){
            $carry *= $item;
            return $carry;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode (number_format(array_reduce($cipher, "product", 1), 0, '.', ''));
?>
```

The test values are: 66300,
170254,
175133,
8226,
82793.

I used an online calculator to know if the product was correct. The correct product is 1346359888376293931758800.

However, the product that PHP is giving is 1346359888376294113542144.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is explained on the php documentation for the [integers](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php) : "The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 5.0.5, and minimum value using the constant PHP_INT_MIN since PHP 7.0.0."

You can also use the [bc_math lib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php):

```
<?php

$res = 1;
foreach ([66300, 170254, 175133, 8226, 82793] as $op) {
    $res = bcmul($res, $op);
}

echo $res; //1346359888376293931758800
```

Comment: This answer made me realise that I was still using Ubuntu 17.04 and had a friend help me update everything on my server. So thank you so much! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You're exceeding 2^31 which starts getting a little unstable; not to worry you arn't the first to experience this issue.

PHP comes with a neat little library called [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php)

Using [gmp_mul](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-mul.php) we can get the value that you require.

```
$ints = array(66300,170254,175133,8226,82793);

$output = 1;
foreach($ints as $i){
    $output = gmp_mul($output,$i);
}

print_r($output);
```

Output : `GMP Object ( [num] => 1346359888376293931758800 )`
[3v4l link](https://3v4l.org/9Nj6q)